# Find the location on the circle marker given angle

Tags: android, android-mapview

I draw a Circle Marker on Google map using the circle option. I have the center point and radius. I want to long/lat of the point on the circle that is x amount of degrees from the X axis.  Any idea how?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601425/draw-a-path-on-maps-following-the-finger-motion-path-on-the-device-screen/26602500#26602500 may give you some idea.

Comment: Thanks but it does not help as my problem is different