# Android Google maps how to draw complex polygon with fillColor

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

am trying to draw free hand shape on google map up to now i can successfully draw Polyline and polygon thanks to @Chintan Khetiya reply at [draw free hand polygon in Google map V2 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android)  and [Draw a path on maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601425/draw-a-path-on-maps-following-the-finger-motion-path-on-the-device-screen) but when i try to draw polygon like below image then "**polygonOptions.fillColor(color)**" d't work i try to convert point into two polygon but its also d't work can any body suggest or like to share any hint or better solution to draw free hand shape with fill color using google maps polygon.

[image: polygon with colid]

here is how i draw polygon

```
fram_map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {     
   @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        int x_co = Math.round(x);
        int y_co = Math.round(y);

        projection = mMap.getProjection();
        Point x_y_points = new Point(x_co, y_co);

        LatLng latLng = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(x_y_points);
        latitude = latLng.latitude;

        longitude = latLng.longitude;

        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        switch (eventaction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // finger touches the screen
                val.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // finger moves on the screen
                val.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // finger leaves the screen
                Draw_Map();
                break;
        }

        if (Is_MAP_Moveable == true) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});

public void Draw_Map() {
    rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    rectOptions.addAll(val);
    rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
    rectOptions.strokeWidth(7);
    rectOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
    polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
}
```

a similar feature is used in **"zillow real estate android app"**

Answer (score 1):

As polygon documentation ( https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon ) shows in the provided example you should close the shape setting as last LatLng a copy of the first one.

So you should edit your listener adding a reference to the LatLng obtained when you perform the ACTION_DOWN and when you perform an ACTION_UP you must insert a new LatLng with the same coords of the previously referenced point.

Happy coding!

Comment: I also tried this, but polygon not fill correctly. what should i do?

Comment: @AhmadVatani do you have intersections in your drawn polygon? because if i remember well the polygon will not fill if there are intersections (not found this in documentation but experienced on some devices)

Comment: Yes. Is there any solution?

Comment: Or how can find path of sections and draw separate polygons??

Comment: @AhmadVatani i "solved" simplifying the polygon with a jts lib. in my specific case losing the holes wasn't a problem. But if you need holes generated by intersections you should find a way to split the drawn polygon in more polygons

Comment: @MarcoCapoferri I am looking for this jts lib for polygon simplification.

Comment: @johnsonjp34 did you ask Google for it? This is the first result on GSearch https://github.com/locationtech/jts